# How do I refresh a circular animation from the background? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation

My app have circle animation [from the framework](https://github.com/rsrbk/SRCountdownTimer) connected to the timer. When the timer is running, the animation starts. If the app goes into the background, the animation stops. When we return to the app, the animation continues from the same place, when did stopped. How do I get the animation to recalculate and start from where the timer is now? [I attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7scO.jpg). All animation methods are concentrated [in one file](https://github.com/rsrbk/SRCountdownTimer/blob/master/SRCountdownTimer/SRCountdownTimer.swift)

Comment: Have you tried with pause() and resume() methods from [framework](https://github.com/rsrbk/SRCountdownTimer)  you mentioned .

Comment: try to pause / resume  animation with layer.speed = 0.0; and on resuming layer.speed = 1.0 in pause() and resume().

Comment: Look at the clock when you go to sleep. Look at the clock when you wake up. Subtract. That's how long you were asleep. Adjust the timer value accordingly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new method in the framework, where I pass the remaining time. The method changes the value in the timer. Thanks guys

```
    public func updateTime(time: Int) {
    elapsedTime = TimeInterval(time)
    delegate?.timerDidResume?(sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.